Segfault when rendering a triangle?
I compile fine but get a segfault. Is it something to do with GLchar * fragmentShaderSource and GLchar * vertexShaderSource?
I have:
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "shader.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

Shader ourShader("core.vs", "core.frag");

const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n";

const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n";

const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main() {
  glfwInit();

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

  GLFWwindow *window =
      glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

  int screenWidth, screenHeight;

  glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

  if (nullptr == window) {
    std::cout << "Failed to create glfw window!\n";
    glfwTerminate();

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

  if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize glew!" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
  GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);

  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
  GLint success;
  GLchar infoLog(512);

  glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

  if (!success) {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog
              << std::endl;
  }

  GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

  if (!success) {
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION::FAILED\n"
              << infoLog << std::endl;
  }

  GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

  glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

  if (!success) {
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING::FAILED\n"
              << infoLog << std::endl;
  }

  glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
  glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

  GLfloat vertices[] = {0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f};

  GLuint VBO, VAO;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                        (GLvoid *)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                        (GLvoid *)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

  glBindVertexArray(0);

  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    ourShader.Use();
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  }

  glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

  glfwTerminate();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

shader.h
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Shader {
public:
  GLuint Program;
  Shader(const GLchar *vertexPath, const GLchar *fragmentPath) {

    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile;

    vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
    fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);

    try {
      vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
      fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
      std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
      vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
      fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
      vShaderFile.close();
      fShaderFile.close();
      vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
      fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
    } catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESSFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
    }

    const GLchar *vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
    const GLchar *fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

    GLuint vertex, fragment;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
      glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog
                << std::endl;
    }

    this->Program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
    glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
    glLinkProgram(this->Program);

    glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
      glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n"
                << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertex);
    glDeleteShader(fragment);
  }

  void Use() { glUseProgram(this->Program); }
};
#endif

core.fs
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{ 
  color vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
}

core.vs
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;"
out vec3 ourColor"
void main()
{
    glPosition = vec 4 (position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;}"


What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

Unrelated: Change void main() to int main()

void main() is correct GLSL.

@user12002570 Note that the void main() signature is only used withing the shaders-- so that's ok.

IIRC the order in which GLFW and GLEW is initialized matter a lot. I think you need to initialize GLEW directly after you initialize GLFW (or was it the other way around?) And you should also check what the initialization functions return, to check if they fail or not. The same when you open the window, check for failure before you use the pointer in glfwGetFramebufferSize.

Are the three quotes in your second shader typos in the question or the contents of your actual shader?

vertexShaderSource isn't pointing to a complete shader. The program first loads the correct shaders from file in the Shader class, but then this is overridden in the rest of the program, where it interprets the string #version 330 core\n as if it were complete shader code.

The parameters used in your two glVertexAttribPointer calls (stride, offset etc.) don't seem to match the data in vertices -- or have I missed something?

Also, the shader program you actually use, Shader ourShader, is global and will be constructed before any OpenGL context exists.

@Someprogrammerdude You want GLFW before GLEW.  GLFW creates the OpenGL context, which is necessary to get the list of supported extensions and their functions.

The variables vertexShaderSource and fragmentShaderSource don't appear to be correctly initialized, as these are not complete shader sources, but the segmentation fault is not related to these variables - it happens earlier.
The main issue is that ourShader of the type Shader is declared at file (global) scope and thus its constructor is run before the main function. The OpenGL function pointers that Shader's constructor uses are not initialized at that point, and will only be initialized after GLEW has been initialized. The program will currently try to use a function pointer that is at, e.g., memory location 0x0, which causes the segmentation fault.
The solution is to move Shader ourShader(...) to after the call to glewInit(). Additionally, both the file with the main function and the shader class contain code that creates a shader program from shader sources. Assuming that the idea is to use a separate class for this, remove the code after setting the viewport to before defining the vertices from the main file. The variables vertexShaderSource and fragmentShaderSource can now be removed as well. Their contents were of no use, and everything from reading the shader sources from file to linking the shader program is now handled by the Shader class.

Additional issues concerning the rendering in OpenGL:

The fragment shader source is missing an = after color, and glPosition should be gl_Position.
The vertex shader souce has a couple of extra quotation marks ("), and is missing a semi-colon after ourColor.
The code for compiling the fragment shader is missing.
The color information is missing from the definition of vertices.
The attributes at position 1 (the colors) are not enabled.


Debugging advice:
The best way to debug a segmentation fault (segfault) is to use a debugger, use a specific tool for debugging memory issues, such as Valgrind, or - if you don't want to use external tools - use print statements to find on what line the segfault occurs and why. In this case, you would find that the first gl* function call in shader.h causes the segfault and that the value of that function pointer is (e.g.) 0. From here, you could reason why this is the case (here: it hasn't been initialized by the OpenGL function loader).
The OpenGL issues could be debugged by, partly looking at the output and reasoning back to the code, and carefully stepping through the code manually and checking if everything is consistent.
Here, you could notice that the code in the fragment shader has no influence on the final image and errors in the code are not reported -> there is no attempt at compiling the fragment shader source.
If the triangle is appearing, but the colors are incorrect, that gives you a hint that the positions are correct, but the color information isn't processed correctly -> check the vertex definitions, attribute specifications and how the colors are processed in the shaders.
The rest is a combination of careful programming and checking the shader source compilation error logs.

The corrected sources:
Main file:
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "shader.h"

const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow (WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    if (nullptr == window)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to create glfw window!\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit())
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to initialize glew!"<<std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Shader ourShader ("core.vs", "core.frag");

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) (3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor(0.2f,0.3f,0.3f,1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        ourShader.Use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1,&VBO);

    glfwTerminate();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Shader.h
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
public:
    GLuint Program;
    Shader(const GLchar * vertexPath, const GLchar * fragmentPath)
    {
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;

        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);

        try
        {
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch(std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout<<"ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESSFULLY_READ"<<std::endl;
        }

        const GLchar * vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const GLchar * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

        GLuint vertex, fragment;
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];

        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout<<"ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED"<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }

        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout<<"ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED"<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }

        this->Program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
        glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(this->Program);

        glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if(!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program,512,NULL,infoLog);
            std::cout<<"ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n"<<infoLog<<std::endl;
        }

        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }

    void Use()
    {
        glUseProgram(this->Program);
    }
};

#endif

core.vs
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec3 ourColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
}

core.fs
#version 330 core

in vec3 ourColor;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
}

I modified the formatting and chose different arbitrary colors for the vertices.

Final result:


2 downvotes now... I have added debugging advice and a screenshot of the working program. Would the downvoters please be so kind to reconsider or to provide feedback?

SO is full of people that are utterly convinced that they know everything. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing.
